# C#: Visual studio code compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a C# (.net core v2.1) solution that built from some of projects. Compile it takes ~90 seconds. This is my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ "${workspaceFolder}\\my.sln"],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my `lunch.json`:

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Tests/Test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Test.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Tests/Test/",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
    ]
}
```

I notice that every time I build the project OR run the current configuration - it compile all the project agian - agian, 90 seconds of waiting.

In previous days, I did it with Visual Studio (the old and good) much more faster - it wasn't compile all the projects UNLESS they changed.

Is this possible to do it with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Hi, what version of .net core SDK do you have? And how big is your code base?

Comment: .net core v2.1. The code base is pretty big. Like 10-15 projects.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith - I think the essential question being asked is whether it is normal that it *always* seems to be doing a *full* build (*".. OR run the current configuration .. [the original VS didn't] compile all the projects UNLESS they changed."*). I don't use VS Code, but I would like to know:  is that normal behavior for VS Code? If so, that would be a severe limitation for a large project. If not, what else would you need in the question, to have an idea as to what might cause that?

Comment: That's true, I was wondering if the .net core SDK in use maybe old with issues perhaps.